# Forking vs Cloning in GitHub

Tags: github, fork, clone

I have a GitHub account and my friend invites me as a collaborator to his project. And now I want to rub the code base locally in my personal computer.

Help me with following;

- Do I need to clone his repo into my personal computer and do changes and then commit.

or

- Do I need to fork the repo, then clone the forked one into my personal computer, do changes and the create a pull request.

I am having doubts about both above methods. Can you help me with that? I want the similarities and differences of each approach.

I tried directly clone from my friend's repo. But after I do that the repo doesn't display on my GitHub profile. Since we do this project as a hobby project, and I need to add this to my portfolio, I would be better if it displays on my GitHub profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forking will create copy of that repo under your own GitHub profile.
Than you will be making changes in your own repository copy, testing everything and finally opening [Pull Request to original repository](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork)

Seems like that's what you want.

Comment: But I also have the edit access to his repo, is it a good practice to fork it or should I clone it from his repo directly.

Comment: @DeshithaGallage Usually when working with multiple people under same project, you just use same repo with different branches. Forking is more fitting for public repositories.